# Setting Default orientation to landscape in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I saw in another question talking about how to find out the orientation, But I want to know how we can set the default orientation of an activity to Landscape in jetpack compose?

I searched through some websites and some videos in YouTube, but I couldn't find it. thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access to `Activity` reference in Compose if you used setContent{} in Activity.

```
val activity = (LocalContext.current as Activity)
activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
```

Comment: thanks man. you helped me a lot today and yesterday. please answer my other question that I always had and didn't find it yet. how you guys know these things?? I searched but I couldn't find. where do you guys look that you can find these, but we normal guys can't find??! please answer this important question. really thanks for helping!

Comment: You mean where i find the answer of these questions? I read official docs, codelabs, google samples, other people's codes, answers of other posters here. Also i created a tutorial that contains answers i post here and more. It's also a playground i use with ease when someone posts a question that requires testing or reproducing the issue. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials

Comment: thanks for answering. I always had this question because I sometimes see some tutorials on YouTube that are unique and I wonder how these guys know these things!!

Comment: Another important thing is asking. I ask a lot either. I asked 46 questions about jetpack compose so far. It's part of the learning process the more resources you consume and practice you learn more as everyone else